# Custom radio button

Tags: reactjs

Подскажите пожалуйста, как на Реакте можно реализовать группу радио кнопок. Необходимо менять класс `checked`/`unchecked` в зависимости от состояния. Структура примерно следующая: http://jsfiddle.net/v5k3pzdc/1/ . 
Основная проблема заключается в том, что состояние кнопки по клику на другую кнопку не меняется, соответственно класс остается.

```
class RadioGroup extends React.Component {
  render() {
  const name = this.props.name;
    return (<div className="radioGroup">
        <RadioButton name={name} />
        <RadioButton name={name} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class RadioButton extends React.Component {

 state = {
    isChecked: false
  };

  handleChange = () => {
    const { isChecked } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      isChecked: !isChecked
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { name } = this.props;
    const { isChecked } = this.state;
    return (
      <label
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        className={isChecked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
      >
        <input
          type="radio"
          name={name}
          checked={isChecked}
        />
        fds
      </label>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<RadioGroup name="lalala"/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынести обработку клика в родительский компонент

```
class RadioGroup extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checkedItem: null;
    };
  }

  onChange = (checkedItem) => {
    this.setState({
      checkedItem: checkedItem;
    });
  }

  render() {
    const name = this.props.name;
    return (<div className="radioGroup">
        <RadioButton 
          name={name}  
          onChange={this.onChange}
          isChecked={this.state.checkedItem === 1}
          itemId={1}
        />
        <RadioButton 
          name={name}  
          onChange={this.onChange}
          isChecked={this.state.checkedItem === 2}
          itemId={2}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class RadioButton extends React.Component {
  handleChange = () => {
    this.props.onChange(this.props.itemId);
  };

  render() {
    const { name } = this.props;
    return (
      <label
        className={this.props.isChecked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
      >
        <input
          type="radio"
          name={name}
          checked={this.props.isChecked}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        fds
      </label>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: такого плана решение у меня было, но мне кажется, что оно не совсем гибкое за счет условия `this.state.checkedItem === 1` и т д

Comment: @VladyslavTereshyn это пример. Ведь у вас все равно должны быть уникальные значения id или value. Можно привязаться к ним, а если значения - массив, то и RadioButton можно поместить в цикл